# http chunked encoding: response works even without the header

Tags: http, http-headers, http-chunked

According the spec, Transfer-Encoding is required for the chunked behavior to work.

However, during debugging I observe that when the header is not in the response, the client appears to handle it just fine.

tcpdump trace is roughly:

Without Transfer-Encoding header:

```
HTTP GET equest
HTTP 200 ok response
a list of Continuation or non-http traffic, of various sizes
8258 Continuation or non-HTTP traffic
16450 Continuation or non-HTTP traffic
```

with Transfer-encoding header:

```
HTTP GET equest
HTTP 200 ok response
a list of Continuation or non-http traffic, of same size 
8266 Continuation or non-HTTP traffic
```

It appears that the client(curl) is not depending on the transfer-encoding header? if so how does it know?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the HTTP headers?  tcpdump does not show these headers.  Try something like Fiddler (browser plugin) or WireShark.

Comment: > GET /testkey HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< date: Tue, 26 Nov 2013 01:31:14 UTC
< expires: Tue, 03 Dec 2013 01:31:14 GMT
< server: tte

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting, comment doesn't seems to parse well.

Comment: It's not supposed to.

Comment: Julian, can you explain more? i am not sure if you are saying 'it's not supposed to work", or something else?